# How to change attribute to a random number using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
    mins = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "yt_min")))
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '20');", mins)
```

I want it to change it to a random number in a specific range instead of 20, I know the randint method but I don't know how to approach it since it's a string

Comment: I'm not familiar with Selenium, but I guess that you're looking for string interpolation: `"arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '{}');".format(randint(1, 100))` (or whatever range you want)

Comment: You generate a random number and convert to a string.  Where are  you stuck on this?

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

A = random.randint(range here)

mins = WebDriverWait(browser,  30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "yt_min")))
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', f'{str(A)}');", mins)
```

Comment: You can do this

Comment: `Message: javascript error: missing ) after argument list`

I am getting this error